# How can I ping some website with parameters on Android? Auch as specifuing the packet size and the ping times?

Tags: android, ping

I foud some Stack Overflow questions such as [Ping Application in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14576710/ping-application-in-android). It uses it like this:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            "/system/bin/ping -c 8 " + url);
```

How can I specify the packet size and the ping times? For example, I want to ping 10 times, and specify the package length is 1472 bytes. How can I do that? Sample code is preferred.

When I modify to

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            "/system/bin/ping -c 8 -s 1472" + url);
```

it does not work. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options for the `ping` command are:

```
shell@android:/ $ ping 
Usage: ping [-LRUbdfnqrvVaA] [-c count] [-i interval] [-w deadline]
        [-p pattern] [-s packetsize] [-t ttl] [-I interface or address]
        [-M mtu discovery hint] [-S sndbuf]
        [ -T timestamp option ] [ -Q tos ] [hop1 ...] destination
```

Comment: thanks,but you mean that i can modify above to this:Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            "/system/bin/ping -c 8 -s 1472 " + url);?