# how to get ping value android

Tags: java, android, ping

I am doing an exercise in Android and I want to display value of a ping. I followed an existing answer ([this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14576710/ping-application-in-android)). The fact is that the code that the person gave doesn't display any information (I toasted it to test the return value of the function "ping"). I called the function like this :

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ping("http://www.stackoverflow.com"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Any other kind of code to simply display ping value ?

I precise that my code is free of any other process, I just want to finally display this result in a small textView.

Here is my code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
private String ping(String url) {

    String str = "";

    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                "/system/bin/ping -c 8 " + url);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                process.getInputStream()));
        int i;
        char[] buffer = new char[4096];
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        while ((i = reader.read(buffer)) > 0)
            output.append(buffer, 0, i);
        reader.close();

        // body.append(output.toString()+"\n");
        str = "ping : " + output.toString();
        // Log.d(TAG, str);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // body.append("Error\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return str;
}

private Button button;
private TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ping("http://www.stackoverflow.com"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            });                     
    }); }
```

Comment: have you added Internet permissions in manifest?

Comment: Nope, what is the specific permission I should add please ?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378607/what-permission-do-i-need-to-access-internet-from-an-android-application

Comment: Thanks for sharing this link asloob but my problem is still present.

Comment: Does it print anything in ADB Log ?

Comment: Yep, it print like the "ping" command in Shell Unix. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try something like here: [Android- Unstable, slow, unreliable PING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32935966/android-unstable-slow-unreliable-ping/32936128#32936128)

**After `public class NameOfYourActivity`**

```
// you need to define this value here, you will need it between "voids", "booleans", ...
long timeofping;
```

**OnCreate:**

```
// button on click listener
Button clickMyButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
clickFirstButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // launch the ping process in a separate thread
            // beacuse of the stability of the app
            new Thread(ping).start();
        }
});
```

**After method "onCreate"**

```
// this code runs after the code bellow ("public Runnable ping ...")
void setPingResult(long pingtime) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), timeofping + " milliseconds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}



// thread of "ping" process
public Runnable ping = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            try {
                long a = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
                Process ipProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
                ipProcess.waitFor();
                timeofping = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000 - a;
            } catch (IOException e)          { e.printStackTrace(); }
            catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

            // update the ping result - we need to call this on the UI thread 
            // because it updates UI elements (TextView)
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                setPingResult(timeofping);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Please fix me, if there are any errors!
Dont forget "imports"! (etc `import android.widget.Toast;`)

Comment: Oh gosh ! Thank you for answering Antonin, I have specialized in HTML/CSS since a long time now but I think i'll go back to Android for a while and I just needed this ! :)

Comment: @Zeratops If this works for you, please check this answer as "answered". Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
yourTextView.setText(ping("http://www.stackoverflow.com"));
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Sparrow_ua, but if the ping result doesn't display in a Toast I have big doubt on the result of your code.

Answer (score -1):

Found my error : need to use IP adresse like `8.8.4.4`instead of domain adress like `www.google.com`. Maybe there is a DNS permission to need ?