# Ping to external server in android

Tags: android

I am writing android code to ping to the server. But the problem is that I can ping only to the localhost serve. When I try to ping external server or host like google.com the code doesnot work.

```
package com.ping;

import java.io.*;
import android.app.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{


TextView text;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    text= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pingview);
    start();

}

protected boolean start()
{
    try
    {
        Runtime runtime1 = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = runtime1.exec("ping -c 1 202.51.67.57"); 
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        String input;

        while((input=reader.readLine())!=null)
        {
            text.setText(input+"\n");
        }

    }

    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(" Exception:"+e);
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

Comment: you are getting any error?

Comment: Check this solution at [Ping Application in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14576710/ping-application-in-android/)