# Laptop can not ping to the android device

Tags: android, windows, ping, arp

I'm trying to do a ping from my Windows 7 laptop to my Android device, but I can not.
I added the Android device to the arp table, I entered this command:

```
netsh interface ipv4 add neighbors "Connection Name" IP ADRESS MAC ADDRESS
```

and I can see the device (ip address ,mac address ) when I type "arp -a ". 
But when I do a  ping I get: timeout exceeded demand. My  laptop (192.168.1.106) and Android device (192.168.1.107 ). They both can ping to the gateway address.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe the device is set to not respond to ICMP requests?

Comment: Many systems are configured not to respond to ping requests, your device might be an example.  Also, android devices can often be unresponsive on wifi until they fully "wake up" the radio and stack as a result of *outbound* traffic *from* the device - so you can try opening a random web page or writing something that runs in the background and does a trivial network operation now and then.

Comment: How can i know if my device does not respond to ICMP requests ? @ Micheal Todd

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219522/is-there-a-way-to-make-an-android-device-answer-to-icmp-pings-addressed-to-the-b) answer seems to imply that ICMP is off on Android phones by default and may require root access for it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem ,by changing the access point ,it was causing the problem.Now i can ping normaly.